# QBOv3 XML Validation Fault 2500 (Invalid Reference Id )

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

I'm trying to create a test invoice at quickbooks using quickbooks-ruby gem. Note I have a test account at QB which doesn't have anything: invoice, customer, etc. It's a new account created only for testing purpose. So here is my code:

```
service = Quickbooks::Service::Invoice.new
service.company_id = current_user.company_id
service.access_token = create_consumer

qb_invoice = Quickbooks::Model::Invoice.new
qb_invoice.customer_id = 123

line_item = Quickbooks::Model::InvoiceLineItem.new
line_item.amount = 100
line_item.sales_item! do |detail|
  detail.unit_price = 100
  detail.quantity = 1
  detail.item_id = 1
end

qb_invoice.line_items << line_item

res = service.create qb_invoice
p res.id #exception!

def create_consumer
  OAuth::AccessToken.new(.....)
end
```

Request:

```
   METHOD = post
   RESOURCE = https://qb.sbfinance.intuit.com/v3/company/fdsfdsfdsfds123/invoice

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Invoice xmlns="http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3" sparse="false">
  <Line>
    <Amount>100.0</Amount>
    <DetailType>SalesItemLineDetail</DetailType>
    <SalesItemLineDetail>
    <ItemRef>1</ItemRef>
    <UnitPrice>100.0</UnitPrice>
    <RatePercent>0.0</RatePercent>
    <Qty>1.0</Qty>
    </SalesItemLineDetail>
  </Line>
  <CustomerRef>123</CustomerRef>
  <TotalAmt>0.0</TotalAmt>
  <Balance>0.0</Balance>
  <Deposit>0.0</Deposit>
</Invoice>
```

and response with the error:

```
RESPONSE CODE = 400

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<IntuitResponse xmlns="http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3" time="2014-03-06T19:30:49.168-08:00">
  <Fault type="ValidationFault">
    <Error code="2500" element="">
      <Message>Invalid Reference Id</Message>
      <Detail>Invalid Reference Id : Something you're trying to use has been deleted. Check the fields with accounts, customers, items, vendors or employees.
      </Detail>
    </Error>
  </Fault>
</IntuitResponse>
```

Could it be because a customer with id = 123 doesn't exist? If not, what's the cause then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please check if you have a customer(ID-123) and Item(Id-1) exist in your account.

If not then create these two entries using apiexplorer/code and use the corresponding object IDs.

ApiExplorer - https://developer.intuit.com/apiexplorer?apiname=V3QBO

EntityRef - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/030_entity_services_reference

ApiExplorer -

[image]

Ref - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0010_getting_started/0015_firstrequest

Thanks

Comment: there is a menu items called "Clients" (not customers). This is it, right? And what's its id, where can I see it? I guess this is in url called "nameId=1" (https://qbo.intuit.com/app/customerdetail?nameId=1), correct?

Comment: Customer and Client refers to same thing(It depends what term you had selected while setting up your QBO account). You can create a customer from QB UI and retrieve the details(including ID) using APIExplorer(which calls customer REST endpoint). You need to use that customer ID in the invoice create API call.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer. However, what's itemID, do I really need it? I created only a customer and succeeded creating a new invoice via API. Why didn't I need itemID, any idea?

Comment: and how can I get itemID?

Comment: If you call getAll endpoint of ITEM entity, then you'll get all Items as XML/json in response. From there you'll find out the itemID. Please refer Invoice entity docs - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/030_entity_services_reference/invoice.

Comment: sorry, I didn't find any mention about "getAll" method there.

Comment: in api explorer -> item at https://developer.intuit.com/apiexplorer?apiname=V3QBO#Item there is no "getAll" either. Do you mean, a query with "select * from Item"?

Comment: yes correct. Please use query endpoint. I meant to say that from devkit side. It has a wrapper like findAll/getAll on top of query endpoint.

Comment: one more question please. I didn't find how to specify name for an item and invoice. Is it possible and how?

Comment: ops, actually "name" exists for Item.

Comment: You don't have to provide the item reference, however, QBO will default to one of the items in your account (lowest QB id?) when the transaction is completed.